# Material-ui Textfield null value for zero

Tags: javascript, material-ui, formik

I have a Material-Ui TextField handled with Formik.
Input value (string) is converted to number on Input Change.

My problem is that when the value number zero passes, it's considered as a false value and renders an empty string.
I want it to get 'number zero' showing in TextField.

If I removes TextField value condition ( `value || ' '` ), It will give me a warning message below.

```
Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components.
```

How can I work around with it ?

### input.js

```
const Input = ({
  classes,
  icon,
  styleName,
  field: { name, value, onBlur },
  form: { errors, touched, setFieldValue },
  ...props
}) => {
  const errorMessage = getIn(errors, name);
  const isTouched = getIn(touched, name);

  const change = (e, name, shouldValidate) => {
    e.persist();
    const inputValue = e.target.value;
    let value;

      if (inputValue !== '') {
        value = isNaN(inputValue) ? inputValue : parseInt(inputValue, 10);
      } else {
        value = null;
      }

    return setFieldValue(name, value, shouldValidate);
  };

  return (
    <TextField
      name={name}
      value={value || ''}
      onChange={e => change(e, name, true)}
      onBlur={onBlur}
      {...props}
      className={classes[styleName]}
      helperText={isTouched && errorMessage}
      error={isTouched && Boolean(errorMessage)}
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            <Icon
              name={icon}
              width="30"
              height="30"
              viewBox="0 0 30 30"
              fill="none"
            />
          </InputAdornment>
        ),
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggested solution did't work for me. 
Number 0 is falsy. so it renders an empty string.
I resolved it with this approach.

```
const input = value === 0 || value ? value : '';
  return (
    <TextField
      name={name}
      value={input}
      ...
    />
  );
```

Comment: Not so important but just wanted to say that with nullish coalescing operator this would also work: `const input = value ?? ''`

Comment: If you want to render "0" for a zero value then `value ?? ''` will not work. You need what @Jiaah put, `value === 0 || value ? value : ''`

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a situation like this in some of our projects.

This isn't specific to `Material-UI` but to `react`.

To work around this, just set the initial value to an empty string `''`.

So far we're fine with setting the value to an empty string since it's the default `event.target.value` of input type `number` when it's empty.

See: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-stonebraker-cgct3

Comment: How did you handle when initial value is 'number zero' with <Input> value prop's set to ' value={ value || " " } ' ? When initial value is number zero, the value is set to an empty string which should not.

Comment: I think you just have to pass the value as it is: `value={value}`?

Comment: Then I have an error message like this. 'Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.'

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry in this case `undefined` won't work since we're using it as a controlled component. You're better off using an empty string as the initial value. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I resolved this issue with a different approach !! Thanks for your time !!